# Cucumber Scala final output shows 0 failures even when a scenario fails

Tags: cucumber, scalatest, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I have a cucumber test suite which has some tests

I run the tests using command

```
sbt "testOnly <cucumber_class_name>"
```

And one of the cucumber tests fail an assertion and console shows

`Failed scenarios:`
`classpath:features/my_cucumber_scenario.feature:31# <my test description>`

19 Scenarios (1 failed, 18 passed)
88 Steps (1 failed, 87 passed)sts 214s
3m18.224s

But in the end the console shows

`Total 80, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 80`

Since one of the tests failed, in the final output it should have shown
`Failed 1` (Or something like that). But it is showing all passed instead due to which my build on travis is not failing.

How to solve this problem ? Is there a solution in cucumber ?

My dependencies are

```
"io.cucumber" % "cucumber-core" % "5.7.0",
"io.cucumber" % "cucumber-junit" % "5.7.0"
"io.cucumber" %% "cucumber-scala" % "5.7.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved by cucumber team in

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm-scala/releases/tag/v6.2.2